# Bind objects from external class

Tags: c#, class, listview, uwp, bind

I want to list objects created in "CreateObjects.cs" to MainPage here is my code:

CreateObjects.cs:

```
class CreateObject
{
static public List<Item> Items;

public static void AddNewItem()
{
Item item = new Item(ID, Name);
}
new List<FileItem>();
}
```

Now I want to bind List to ListView control on Mainpage.xaml.
Is there a way to read that list on Mainpage?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:CreateObject.Items}}" />
```